# How do I define an event as occuring whenever a particular set of circumstances are true?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

Long story short I have two boolean variables called FirstBool and SecondBool. I have a program which uses two delegates to run two methods asynchronously. I am using `Console.ReadLine()` to keep the parent thread alive while the child thread runs.

When the first method completes, FirstBool is set to true. When the second method completed, SecondBool is set to true.

Long story short, I want to define my event as "`FirstBool` and `SecondBool` are both true", and close my program at this time. The only alternative I can see to this is to poll both boolean values until they are both true and then close the program, and polling sucks.

My code is below:

```
class Program
{
    private delegate void MyDelegate();

    private static bool FirstBool { get; set; }
    private static bool SecondBool { get; set; } 

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FirstBool = false;
        SecondBool = false;

        MyDelegate firstDelegate = new MyDelegate(FirstMethod);
        MyDelegate secondDelegate = new MyDelegate(SecondMethod);

        AsyncCallback myCallback = new AsyncCallback(CallbackMethod);

        firstDelegate.BeginInvoke(myCallback, "Zip");
        secondDelegate.BeginInvoke(myCallback, "Line");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void CallbackMethod(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        switch (result.AsyncState.ToString())
        {
            case "Zip":
                FirstBool = true;
                break;
            case "Line":
                SecondBool = true;
                break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Callback Method");
    }

    private static void FirstMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("First Method");
    }

    private static void SecondMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Second Method");
    }
}
```

So, long story short, how do I create an event whose definition is "`FirstBool` is true and `SecondBool` is true" and run a method on this events occurence?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to .NET 4, then you can very easily accomplish this with the Task Parallel Library:

```
var taskOne = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
   {
       // Do Stuff
   });

var taskTwo = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
   {
       // Do Other Stuff
   });

Task.WaitAll(taskOne, taskTwo);

// Quit
```

If you're using an older version of .NET, then you simply need to call the `EndInvoke` method to wait for the asynchronous calls to complete:

```
 SomeDelegate x = SomeMethod;
 SomeDelegate y = SomeOtherMethod;

 var iar1 = x.BeginInvoke(null, null);
 var iar2 = y.BeginInvoke(null, null);

 // Program would still be executing here...

 x.EndInvoke(iar1);
 y.EndInvoke(iar2);

 // Quit
```

Answer (score 1):

In the setter for each of the booleans, check if both of them are going to be true.  If they are, you can run your method.

Here's an example of how you could do it:

```
public static object syncLock = new object();

private static bool myFirstBool;
private static bool mySecondBool;
private static bool FirstBool {
    get { return myFirstBool; }
    set {
        lock (syncLock) {
            if (value && mySecondBool) {
                CallbackMethod(null);
            }
            myFirstBool = value;
        }
    }
}
private static bool SecondBool {
    get { return mySecondBool; }
    set {
        lock (syncLock) {
            if (value && myFirstBool) {
                CallbackMethod(null);
            }
            mySecondBool = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is a very difficult and error prone way to accomplish your goal.

Have a look at this article, it will help accomplish what you want to do in a much safer and better way

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For the specific application, I would stronly recommend using a synchronisation primitive like a `System.Threading.ManualResetEvent` or - as you wait for two events - a `System.Threading.Semaphore`. You would create a semaphore variable with an initial count of zero and a maximum count of two. Instead of setting a `bool`, you call `Release()` and in the main thread you wait for the semaphore being signaled twice.